# how to use a new variable dynamically created

Tags: powershell

Here is a simple script :

---

```
$MyDb = "xt1"
$Var01 = $MyDb
$Var01
$Var02 = "Error"
$DynamicMyVar = "{0}Custom{1}" -f $var02,$Var01
new-variable -name $DynamicMyVar
$DynamicMyVar
```

---

The value of the variable $DynamicMyVar is (in fact) "ErrorCustomxt1".
And I need to use this value as a variable without knowing with what values it was built.
$var01 and $var02 are variables that get values by program and I don't know them,
But I need to build a new variable name that will be composed of their values, 
and so use the new variable in the next steps of my program.

Thank you !

Comment: Use `set-variable $dynamicmyvar -value 'data'` to update the variable value. Then use `get-variable $dynamicmyvar -ValueOnly` to retrieve the value.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you not use a hashtable?

```
$hash = [hashtable]::new()

$hash['Var01'] = "xt1"
$hash['Var02'] = "Error"

$newKey = $hash['Var01'] + 'Custom' + $hash['Var02']

$hash[ $newKey ] = "Hi"

$newKey
$hash[ $newKey ]
```

Comment: Nice, but I must use the variable in the program. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem by using the Invoke-Expression that can manipulate dynamic variable (defined by the program and not known by the programmer). The first step is to define the new variable (so we could use it later in the program). The second step is to build an expression. The third step is to execute this expression using the variable.
Here is the script :

## Defining The Error$Db variable...

```
$Var01 = "xt1"
$Var01
$Var02 = "Error"
$DynamicMyVar = "{0}{1}" -f $var01,$Var02
new-variable -name $DynamicMyVar
$DynamicMyVar


$MyDb = "xt1"
# Initializing Error$MyDb ...
$MyStmt = "$"+$MyDb+"Error=0"
$MyStmt
Invoke-Expression $MyStmt
# Incrementing Error$MyDb ...
$MyStmt = "$"+$MyDb+"Error="+"$"+$Mydb+"Error+1"
$MyStmt
Invoke-Expression $MyStmt
#
```